# Paste bidimensional array of Double values with 3 decimal positions lose separator and turn into thousands

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to paste a two-dimensional array of Variant/String into a range. That's no problem.
This Variant/String columns can contain strings or double values.

All works fine except in those cells where the double value contains 3 decimal values or more.
Comma (,) is the decimal separator and dot (.) is the thousand separator for my Excel.

e.g.:

When coming 2,3 in the array, it pastes 2,3 in the Excel cell

When coming 2,34 in the array, it pastes 2,34 in the Excel cell

When coming 2,321 in the array, it pastes 2321 in the Excel cell.value and shows 2.321 in cell.text

When coming 2,3215 in the array, it pastes 23215 in the Excel cell.value and shows 23.215 in cell.text

Code:

```
Dim DataArray(2, 2) As Variant 
...
... code that fills DataArray
...
Range("A1").Resize(UBound(DataArray, 1) + 1,UBound(DataArray, 2) + 1).Offset(1, 0) = DataArray
```

Comment: Have you checked the number format of your range?

Comment: In `... code that fills DataArray`, get sure that `Double` is assigned to `DataArray(?,?)`, instead of `String`, which is happening.

Comment: Better, use `Dim DataArray(2,2) As Double`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. It's just a classic case of Excel misinterpreting the variant end type. Unfortunately, that neat vector formula for populating your range has to go. Instead you could use something like this (i and j specify the upper-left cell of your variable range):

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim x As String
Dim i as integer, j as integer
'The first cell is "A1"
i=1
j=1

For Each cell In Range(Cells(i,j),Cells(i+UBound(DataArray, 1),j+Ubound(DataArray)))
  x = DataArray(cell.Row - i, cell.Column - j)
  cell.Value = x
  'Next line is optional
  If IsNumeric(x) Then cell.NumberFormat = "General"
Next cell
```

Tested and it works. 
If you omit the optional line Excel will guess the format but it will mostly be correct. If you know what format you want for your numbers then definitely specify it on the optional line. You can try other formats such as "###,##0.00" if you want to specify the number of decimals.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Hi! That was my next step. Iteration. Works well, but the problem is the same, when you got 3 decimal or more values, it loses decimal separator and turn to thousands... :(.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Works well with the next modification:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim x As String
Dim D as Double
Dim i as integer, j as integer
'The first cell is "A1"
i=1
j=1

For Each cell In Range(Cells(i,j),Cells(i+UBound(DataArray, 1),j+Ubound(DataArray)))
  x = DataArray(cell.Row - i, cell.Column - j)
  If IsNumeric(x) Then 
      D = CDbl(x)
      cell.Value = D
  Else
      cell.value = x
  end if
Next cell
```

Thank you so much!!! :)